# OrientDB in distributed architecture works with vertex replication across servers?

Tags: database, performance, orientdb, distributed-computing, database-replication

I have worked in a project with OrientDB graph database. I've managed to fill the database and perform the queries in it without problems. But after I needed to run my queries using the distributed feature from OrientDB, and I came with an important (maybe trivial) doubt.

I've managed to use the distributed mode also without problems using 3 differente machines, but I wanted to be sure that OrientDB is really storing my database within the 3 machines that I've used. Is there any way to check that?

When I was researching for this answer, I came to the conclusion that OrientDB replicates the entire database across all the machines, is that correct? The goal to use the distributed architecture was to improve performance, but if OrientDB works with replication, and I run one query in a specific machine, the query will be processed using all machines, or only one?

To be short, I want to know if OrientDB when using the distributed mode, distributes the vertex and edges across the machines, and process the queries using all the machines?

I've read the entire documentation : http://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/Distributed-Architecture.html and could not find a clear explanation for this questions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See: http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Replication.html and http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Distributed-Sharding.html

Comment: Hi @OleksandrGubchenko thanks for helping me. I've seen those links, but I cannot really understand if OrientDB replicates the entire database across all machines, or it distributes the vertex and edges ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OrientDB, by default, replicates the entire DB on all the servers. What you're looking for is called ["Sharding"](https://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/Distributed-Sharding.html). OrientDB supports manual sharding (automatic in the future), that means you (the application) can decide where to store the vertices/edges.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: Regarding the performance improvement, without sharding if I run a query in distributed mode, the processing will be done with all the machines? Probably not right?

Comment: Without sharding means all the servers have the same data, right? For this reason, the query is executed only on the local server for performance reasons. You can connect your client to N servers with a ROUND_ROBIN connection strategy, so you will use all the servers anyway.

Comment: Awesome makes sense! But just to confirm, this strategy of ROUND_ROBIN is for load distribution correct? What I want to achieve is concurrent processing in my query. Probably, with sharding this is achieved automatically.